# CKEditor inside FancyBox edit disabled

Tags: fancybox, ckeditor

I tray to use CKEditor inside FancyBox, all work great, but if i try to add for ex. table all fields is disabled. (I attach an image. The same for image, flash...)

I try to open CKEditor without FancyBox and it's work OK but i need like with FancyBox.
[image]

Comment: any chance for you to share a link? it would be much easier to debug than an image ;)

Comment: No problem. But i only use CKEditor and groceryCRUD together. I can't see any problem or conflicts with firebug or other tools. This is exact problem as Reinmar described.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery UI (which I believe is used in your system, but in fact the same issue occures when using Twitter Bootstrap) is blocking all inputs in CKEditor's dialogs. It seems that guys from jQuery UI were working on this issue, but I'm not sure if new version, including this fix, has been already released.

Check [this bug report](https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/10081) on CKEditor trac for more info.